# URL available only for administrator

Tags: symfony

How can I set that URL`s which have new in name are available only for ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR?

I`m sure that I must set it in security.yml  access_control
But how to set for example
www.mydomain.com/user/new

www.mydomain.com/user/2/edit

only for ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR

- { path: ^/.*/new, role: ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR } doesn`t work :(

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 2 will select the first pattern that matches. So, if a pattern above the one you shared gives access to that path (say something like `^/user`) then the role of that line will be allowed.

Ensure that you have the restrictive paths above all of the others.

Also, I'm not sure if Symfony allows . to match /, so you might want to try `^/[\s\S]*/new` (or even just `/new$` if the new is always at the end) if it isn't just a problem with ordering.